# math on minted : strange spacing

Tags: math-mode, minted

I am using the `minted` package to show codes in LaTeX. I want to insert a math formula in my comments, but the formula looks strange. There are much more space before and after the ≤ symbol than expected:

[image: ()]

As you can see, the "1≤n≤100" above is the spacing that I want, but the "1≤n≤100" in the comment seems to have too much spacing. How can I solve this? Thanks.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
$1\le n\le 100$.
\begin{minted}[mathescape,baselinestretch=1]{python}
def a(n) :
    return 1 <= n && n <= 100 # $1 \le n\le 100$
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I'm on Windows 10, using CTeX, WinEdt 7.0. This is the output of PDFTeXify. Hope this helps.

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "tmp"
Startup Folder: F:\tmp

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: tmp.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file tmp.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file tmp.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file tmp.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--shell-escape --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=1 "F:\tmp\tmp.tex"
Startup Folder: F:\tmp

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(F:/tmp/tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for loaded.
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\minted\minted.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)) (C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty)))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\float\float.sty)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\ifplatform\ifplatform.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\catchfile.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty))))找不到 F:\tmp\tmp.aex

F:\tmp>set  /p x=C:\Python27\Scripts\pygmentize.exe 0<nul: 1>>tmp.aex 

F:\tmp>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>tmp.aex 

F:\tmp>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>tmp.aex 

file deleted
(F:\tmp\tmp.aux) (C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (F:\tmp\tmp.pyg) (F:\tmp\tmp.out.pyg) [1{C:/CTEX/UserData/pdftex/config/pdfte
x.map{Unicode.sfd}{UGBK.sfd}}] (F:\tmp\tmp.aux) )<C:/CTEX/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmitt10.pfb><C:/CTEX/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmm
i10.pfb><C:/CTEX/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/CTEX/MiKTe
X/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><C:/CTEX/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on tmp.pdf (1 page, 40459 bytes).
SyncTeX written on tmp.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on tmp.log.


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 1)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

P.S. Maybe I should put my `minted` version here? But how do I see my `minted` version?

Edit2: My python version is 2.7.12.

Comment: May it be that `minted` switches to mono-spaced fonts and applies that spacing even on math (at least spaces)?

Comment: I get normal spacing: [click here for a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw9BK.png) Can you add some details about your setup?

Comment: @egreg How do you mean by "details about my setup"? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of `minted`, `mathescape` didn't behave exactly like normal math mode in a number of ways, including the treatment of spaces. Recent versions of `minted` (2.3 and later) load `fvextra`, which causes `mathescape` to behave more as expected.

Based on your log, `fvextra` isn't loaded, so you are probably using an old version of `minted`. Updating should fix this.